# Create a table from a table with same row values on 1 or more columns and a third column with new logic

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this -

| Host_ID | PCI_ID | Class_ID | Device_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 230 | 04:00.0 | 512 | Cisco VIC |
| 230 | 03:00.0 | 512 | Cisco VIC |
| 230 | 04:01.0 | 512 | Cisco VIC |
| 230 | ff:00.0 | 1040 | CPU Xeon |
| 451 | 04:00.0 | 512 | Cisco VIC |
| 451 | 03:00.0 | 512 | Cisco VIC |
| 451 | ef:00.0 | 1040 | CPU Xeon |
| 671 | 03:01.0 | 512 | Cisco VIC |
| 671 | 02:00.0 | 512 | Cisco VIC |
| 671 | ff:00.0 | 1040 | CPU Xeon |

I want to have a table like below which will have rows where CLASS_ID=514 and is sorted by HOST_ID,PCI_ID and will have a third column called 'Name' which will have integer appended to text 'vmnic' for each row with same HOST_ID (vmnic0,vmnic1,vmnic2 etc)

| Host_ID | PCI_ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 230 | 04:00.0 | vmnic0 |
| 230 | 03:00.0 | vmnic1 |
| 230 | 04:01.0 | vmnic2 |
| 451 | 04:00.0 | vmnic0 |
| 451 | 03:00.0 | vmnic1 |
| 671 | 03:01.0 | vmnic0 |
| 671 | 02:00.0 | vmnic1 |

I currently have something like this to start with -

```
SELECT 
     HOST_ID as ID
    ,PCI_ID as PCIe_Address
    ,'vmnic'+ <LOGIC for appending INT> as Name 
FROM VPX_HOST_PCI_DEVICE
WHERE CLASS_ID=512
ORDER BY HOST_ID,PCI_ID
```

Can anyone help me with the sql server code for LOGIC for appending INT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the correct number to append. You need to `CONVERT` it to `VARCHAR` to avoid conversion error

```
SELECT
    HOST_ID AS ID,
    PCI_ID AS PCIe_Address,
    'vmnic' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HOST_ID ORDER BY PCI_ID DESC) - 1) AS Name
FROM VPX_HOST_PCI_DEVICE
WHERE
    CLASS_ID = 512
ORDER BY
    HOST_ID, PCI_ID
```

Comment: This worked! Only edit was that I wanted it in ASC order not DESC! Thanks Felix!!